# A unknown IP logged into my gmail

Tags: gmail

Unknown login to my Gmail account: IP 192.168.12.54. I cannot remove this IP now.

It also says chacha20_poly1305 uses x25519 key exchange mechanism.

Comment: 192.168.1.254 is a private IP address.  If that IP address is coming from Google, it's likely some internal process inside Google logging in.

Comment: You just show some statement taken out of any useful context. Is this a message presented to you when you login into gmail, is it something you've got in a mail claiming to be from gmail or whatever this is.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the IP? Where are you seeing these messages?